# Syntax Error in Verilog 4'b0000

Tags: verilog

I seem to have run into a strange Syntax error. So far as I was concerned it shouldn't be wrong? I've tried it with multiple simulations on EDA Playground. They all return a syntax error.

Here's the code:

```
//varaibles to store temp reg ID's
  reg [3:0] reg_d, reg_s, reg_t;

  always @* begin
    reg_d = 4’b0000;
    reg_s = 4’b0000;
    reg_t = 4’b0000;
```

I do more things and close it off fine. Here's the error.

```
Error-[SE] Syntax error
  Following verilog source has syntax error :
  "wramp.sv", 64: token is '\037777777742'
      reg_d = 4\037777777742\037777777600\037777777631b0000;
```

It seems like it's the `'` but yeah. I searched google all over for correct syntax, but can't find anything wrong with what I have. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Comparing the error message's `'` and the code's `’` I'm pretty sure that character is wrong. Delete them and rewrite as proper `'`

Comment: Why are they different? But thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Copypaste from somewhere where some automat changes the characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apostrophes used in the code aren't the "proper" apostrophes. If you look at the error message or the comment in the beginning of the code the character `'` is the proper one while in the code there is a `’`. These characters won't work so you have to change them to the proper versions.